# How to create a database and connect to it in ASP.NET MVC 4 by using Code First Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am using:

- VMware V10.0.1.
- Visual Studio Ultimate 2013.
- SQL Server 2012.

I created an ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application and I want to build a database by using the Code First technique from Entity Framework.

The database is really simple while it has only one table (User) with the following field (UserId, Username, Name, Surname). In order to build it I created the following class in C# :

```
namespace MyQuestionProject.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }

        public User()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I also created my Context class which is the one shown below:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyQuestionProject.Models
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        public Context() : base("name=UserDBConnectionString")
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I have changed also my connection string in "Web.config" file and the changed connection string is the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="UserDBConnectionString"  connectionString="Data Source=stavra-dev;Server=STAVRA-DEV;Database=UserDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and in order to be able to observe that the connection is really established, I added some code which actually adds a record to the database. I used razor in my "index.cshtml" in my "home" folder. The code is the one below:

```
@using MyQuestionProject.Models

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@{
    using (var ctx = new Context())
    {
        User stud = new User() { UserId = 1, Username = "StaVra", Name = "Stavros", Surname = "Vrakas"};

        ctx.Users.Add(stud);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The previous code is correct, but the connection string seems that it does not work.

I followed the information regarding Code First in >>[this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)<< Web site and I found information about SQL Server 2012 Connection String in >>[this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)<< site.

It has been some days I am trying to figure out how I can manage to make that work and I will appreciate any assistance that can be provided on this topic.

Any suggestion or idea is more than welcome.

---

The Entity Framework Version is 5.0.0.0 and Runtime Version v4.0.30319

I changed the providerName to "System.Data.SqlClient"

The error that occures is the following:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

@jebar8
@DominicZukiewicy

Comment: Is this for SQL Server? The providerName attribute should be `System.Data.SqlClient`.

Comment: Yes it is for SQL Server 2012. I tried "System.Data.SqlClient" too, but it does't work.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - can you be more specific? Is there an error? Or does it just run through with no problems?

Comment: Also - what version of Entity Framework are you using ? 5 or 6?

Comment: As @jebar8 stated the provider should indeed be `System.Data.SqlClient`. And I don't think that you need to provide DataSource and Server (I usually only user Server). If you get any exceptions from EF that would be helpful too.

Comment: P.S. I've never seen anyone write DAL code in the View before :-)

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz how is it possible that you've built up that much S.O. reputation without *ever* seeing this in a question before? :)

Comment: @jebar8: I would normally have to take myself for a walk. But this deserves a wall of fame :-)

Comment: @user3569034 Are you getting an exception thrown?

Comment: @jebar8 I changed the providerName to "System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

@jebar8 I changed the providerName to "System.Data.SqlClient" and I tried to set only the Server in connection string, but the error still appears.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz I wrote the error that I get and I tried to find more information about it but still I din't get anything tha help.

Comment: @mxmissile I updated my post and I included the thrown exception.

In case somebody has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Is System.Data.SqlClient referenced in the project?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz No, "System.Data.SqlClient" is not included as a reference. I tried to add it now that you suggested me, but there was only System.Data.SqlXml available. My question now is where can I find "System.Data.SqlClient" so that I can include it in my references

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is part of `System.Data`. Is `System.Data` referenced in the project containing the Entity Framework assembly?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz Yes "System.Data" is included as a reference and there are also referenced the following two: System.Data.DataSetExtensions and System.Data.Entity

Comment: Can you GitHub your project so we can see it and work out what is wrong?

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz I will send the new code in GitHUB

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it

```
public Context() : base("UserDBConnectionString") {}
```

instead of

```
public Context() : base("name=UserDBConnectionString") {}
```

?

Comment: @efzwo I tried both and there is no difference. I found the format in a video in www.pluralsight.com and I am sure it is correct.

Comment: That's because the constructor of DbContext takes that given string directly. See also the example in a new MVC5 Application in VS2013 (used in ApplicationDbContext)

Comment: @efzwo I recreated the project in MVC5 and I have also installed Entity Framework package with this command (Install-Package EntityFramework).
Thanks for the link efzwo (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: Now I have an other exception and it is the following:

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: @DominicZukiewicz I will send the code new code in GitHUB